# Usar vista de diseño de NetBeans para cualquier clase que sea un elemento gráfico

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, matisse

Estoy aprendiendo Java y en este momento estoy aprendiendo a hacer mis propios entornos gráficos con swing.

En eclipse (no recuerdo muy bien si tuve que instalar un plugin o no) pero he notado que se puede abrir en vista de diseño cualquier clase que extienda algun elemento grafico. En cambio, he notado que en NetBeans la unica manera de usar la vista de diseño es crear un jFrame o un jPanel desde el asistente, pero no puedo habilitar la vista de diseño en un archivo existente.

Por motivos de preferencia personal prefiero NetBeans pero me gustaria poder lograr dicho comportamiento de Eclipse en él.

Desde ya gracias.

Comment: es casi lo mismo...

Comment: bueno, el "casi" hace la diferencia

Answer (score 1):

para aprender quizá sea más intuitivo Netbeans pero luego en la vida laboral se usa bastante más eclipse entonces bueno yo te puedo echar una mano con netbeans ya que empecé con ello, pero lo suyo es que sigas con eclipse y efectivamente necesitaste instalar " Windows Build Tools " para usarlo en Eclipse

Digamos que tienes varias formas de hacer la interfaz una es con la ayuda del propio netbeans con swing y otra seria a código puro y duro haciendo que se levante las ventanas y creando tu los jframe y este ultimo caso no tienes opción de verlo en acción a medida que vas programándolo

[image: Inserccion Jframe]

Por ejemplo aquí muestro una interfaz sencilla que realice en su día, como podemos ver en la parte de arriba aparece Source / Design / History moviéndonos entre esas ventanas podremos ir poniendo codigo y editando las ventanas la parte Design será donde puedas arrastras las cosas de swing y ponerlo  a tu gusto de forma muy visual y cómoda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 en el apartado Source podremos ver los códigos usados para crear la siguiente ventana

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirviera de ayuda, 
PDT: el código que está en gris se debe editar desde los códigos generados ( dado que se ponen automáticamente)

Comment: No es necesariamente código puro la única alternativa, matisse soporta fácilmente que le agregues componentes personalizados, incluso soltando y arrastrando siempre y cuando dicho componente sea un bean

Answer (score 0):

Con [matisse](/questions/tagged/matisse) puedes usar la vista diseño para practicamente cualquier componente gráfico (interfaces o clases abstractas es lo único que no se puede), siempre y cuando cumpla con la especificación Java Beans, si revisas [jcalendar](/questions/tagged/jcalendar), verás que le metí el GUI Builder de netbeans a muchos de los componentes.

Esta característica no es nueva, pero en últimas versiones se ha refinado para poderse realizar de la siguiente manera:

Yo veo dos casos posibles, para agregar un componente personalizado a una clase que ya tiene el GUI Builder activado puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. En el componente que quieras, por ejemplo un Panel usas la opción de la paleta llamado ChooseBean, que viene en la sección de Beans [image: Choose bean]
2. Debes de escribir el nombre totalmente calificado (Fully Quialified Name) de tu clase [image: Nombre totalmente cualificado de un componente visual]
3. Personalizas y ublicas en el lugar que quieras[image: componentes visuales personalziados usables en matisse]

La segunda opción que se me ocurre es que el componente que deseas no sea ni JFrame, ni JPanel con los siguientes pasos:

1. vamos al asistente y seleccionamos un nuevo "Bean Form" [image: Nuevo Bean Form]
2. La primera parte del sistente se llena normal[image: primer dialogo del asistente de creación de bean form]
3. En la segunda parte debes especificar le nombre totalmente cualificado de la clase visual que vas a heredar[image: segundo daligo del asistente de creación de bean form]

Matisse se encargará de la configuración en el archivo `.form` y te mostrará un resultado visual.

En versiones mega rucas de netbeans, en las que no existía el primer método, lo que hacias era arrastrar y soltar la clase desde la vista de proyecto a la ventana de tu GUI designer, se agregaba a la sección other components y de allí ya lo podías posicionar a donde quisieras en la jerarquía.

Comment: Creo que ya se por donde va tu respuesta... Pero no la termino de entender por completo.
Entendí que, matisse es el editor grafico para interfaces graficas y solamente se habilita en netbeans cuando el código cumple determinadas especificaciones.
Supongo que debería aprender sobre Java Beans para poder entender el resto.